# regular expression validation using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a text based upon a regular expression in javascript. My regular expression is working fine but but can't find out why it is not working in java script.

The regular expression is this , `^([-+/*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*`

Valid expressions are `+7` or `+9.36*8` or `+4-9.3/5.0`

Invalid matches are `test` or `8.36`

Here is the code,

```
    var ck_diffrentialformula = /^([-+/*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*/;

            function radtxtbxLinkedDifferentialFormulaOnBlur(sender, eventArgs) {
                if (sender.get_value().length > 0) {

                    var entered_value = sender.get_value();

                    if (ck_diffrentialformula.test(entered_value)) {
                     alert('Text Matches');
                    }
                    else {
                     alert('Text does not match');
                    }
                }
            }

sender.get_value() - gives the text box value over here.
```

Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: are u getting any of the alerts?

Comment: Please provide an example of the actual data that needs to be validated (both a valid and an invalid example would be best).

Comment: It would help us to know the value of `sender.get_value()` immensely (and what you expect the alert to be).

Comment: @Sirwani - Yes, but even if I enter the correct format it gives me error message.

Comment: @lanzz - updated my question with valid expressions

Comment: @Ray Toal - updated my question

Comment: You're right that your regex is fine (see http://jsfiddle.net/rtoal/39brt/) but again, what is `sender.get_value()`?  Is `sender` a text field, by any chance :) ?  If so, see sachleen's answer.

Comment: @Ray Toal - updated my question

Comment: Alert the value of `entered_value` right after you declare it.  Then enter `+7` into the textbox. See if it alerts.  Unless you defined `get_value` on your own, you will not see it.

Comment: @Ray Toal - Yes I have done that I am getting it also, I think some modifications has to be done to the regular expression as it contains special symbols.

Comment: Your code, _exactly as it is_, works with absolutely no problems and matches all your test data: http://jsbin.com/etigug/edit#source

Comment: jsbin says you should escape "-" and "/" within the regex.

Comment: @Jasd - what characters should be escaped in this "^([-+/*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*"

Comment: @lanzz - its also accepting the invalid matches

Comment: @Bibhu you haven't provided any invalid example data.

Comment: @Bibhu according to jsbin you should escape "-" and "/", so your regex would become `^([\-+\/*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*`

Comment: @jasd: yes, it does warn, but if those unescaped characters were the cause, the regex definition would have given a syntax error and no alerts would be given at all.

Comment: @lanzz - updated the question with invalid examples

Comment: @Bibhu: your regex accepts the invalid examples, because you're looking for _zero_ or more valid portions at the beginning of the string; the invalid examples have _zero_ valid portions, thus they satisfy your regex. Change the final `*` in the regex to a `+`, so it will only accept _one_ or more matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try this expression: `/^([\-+\/*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*$/`
It escapes "-" and "/" (jsbin suggests it) within the regex and considers the whole string (`$` at the end).

Comment: Thanks, it works just I had to add an extra escape character. The correct regular expression is `/^([\-+\/\*]\d+(\.\d+)?)*$/`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using it something like this:

```
<input type="text" onchange="radtxtbxLinkedDifferentialFormulaOnBlur(this,null)" />
```

`sender` has no method `.get_value()` so that won't even work. Replacing that, it seems to work.

```
function radtxtbxLinkedDifferentialFormulaOnBlur(sender, eventArgs) {
    console.log(sender)
    if (sender.value.length > 0) {
        console.log(sender.value);
        if (ck_diffrentialformula.test(sender.value)) {
         console.log('Text Matches');
        }
        else {
         console.log('Text does not match');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my question, I am getting the textbox value using 'sender.get_value()' and the value is also coming

Comment: So `sender.getValue()` returns the correct value... all you have left is an if statement. Syntax is valid. Something else is wrong. Show us the getvalue code

Comment: `sender.getValue()` returns the correct value i have checked it using an alert box

Comment: can you alert `entered_value`?

Comment: If you can get that far, it should alert something because you have an `if` and an `else`... something else is causing this. youll have to share the whole code. I honestly don't understand. your code works as is.